# When writing to the CSV, the written text ignores line break and writes on the same line, why?

Tags: php, html, csv

When the code below executes and writes to the csv-file, the written line ignores line break in the csv-file and it becomes a part of the previous line instead of an independent one. I've tried using `\n` to try and get a line break in, but no different result.

```
$fylke = $_POST['fylke'];
$kommune = $_POST['kommune'];
$lokasjon = $_POST['lokasjon'];
$sno = $_POST['sno'];
$dato = $_POST['dato'];

if(!isset($error)){

    $Content .= "$fylke,$kommune,$lokasjon,$sno,$dato \n";

    $FileName = fopen("formdata.csv", "a");

    foreach ((array) $Content as $line) {

        fputcsv($FileName,explode(',',$line));
    }

    fclose($FileName);
```

Comment: @JaxonCrosmas its a csv file not a web page

Comment: `fputcsv` should add a new line. How are you viewing the resulting CSV? In a text editor?

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of related questions lately.  This is either a poorly-taught class, or a lazy class.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, I'm using WinSCP's text editor

Comment: @PatrickQ the correct one there is poorly-taught upper secondary class

Comment: I don't see how casting a string to an array is going to do anything to the string.   I think you're writing once, everything, in one line.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to worry about linebreaks when using [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php). You can store your values in an array and then just loop over each. `fputcsv()` will automatically add a new-line every time it gets called. if you want some special delimiter for your csv you can set the third parameter to this. Here is an example.

```
...

//push new line-array
$Content[] = [$fylke, $kommune, $lokasjon, $sno, $dato];

foreach ($Content as $line)
    fputcsv ($FileName, $line, ',');  // the commata is the delimiter (default csv-delimiter)

...
```

Comment: I tried this with no luck, sadly, I got the same result as before.

Comment: Could it be that your programm to view the csv-file maybe has wrong options set so it looks not for linebreaks as delimiter of csv-lines?

Comment: It couldn't be, this problem didn't exist before just recently, maybe a couple hours ago, I have no clue why this problem popped up. Not to mention I've got a second file which makes a diagram of the csv file, and that even shows the issue quite clearly.

Comment: @SimenLeoBFZodiac open the file with a text-editor and check if there are linebreaks and correct delimiter set.

Comment: I tried opening it with Notepad, and Notepad++ same issue reoccurred. The issue is that without an extra empty line underneath the previous line, the arrays aren't created properly, the issue with having an empty line is that, that creates an issue when I'm trying to make the diagram using this csv.

CSV-file with the empty line [marked in blue]:https://i.imgur.com/pTrBIRH.png 
CSV-file without empty line after adding more info: https://i.imgur.com/twZdZk8.png

Comment: @SimenLeoBFZodiac add the newline after reading the csv. not in it

Comment: that line was not added manually, it was added by the form. Also, I figured out away around the issue. In my other php-script/code I just made a check for "if" the variable was empty (aka an empty line) and said, if it was empty, "break". it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If `$Content` is an array, you append to it by doing `$Content[] =` not `$Content .=`.

Then you will not need to cast to an array here:

```
foreach((array) $Content as $line) {
```

... it can be just ...

```
foreach($Content as $line) {
```